# Summing all float entities within a Database on App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm just wondering what the proper way to go about doing this is. I have a database that contains floats, and I am simply trying to get the sum total of all floats in the database.

Example:

```
class Sum_DB(db.Model):
    name_of_profile = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    float_value= db.FloatProperty()


sum_me_up  = db.GqlQuery("select * from Sum_DB WHERE name_of_profile =:1", profile_id)
```

If someone could just give me a hand here, I would be grateful. I've tried messing around with fetch() but haven't been able to get a sum or list of values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry if I'm misunderstanding, but it sounds like you want to retrieve a group of entities from the datastore and sum their respective `float_value` properties. If that is what you want to do, you will need to set up a query that pulls all of the entities in question (here we will just use `Sum_DB.all()` to pull all of them) and then iterate through the returned list of objects, summing their `float_value` property. For example:

```
class Sum_DB(db.Model):
    name_of_profile = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    float_value= db.FloatProperty()


class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
    r = Sum_DB(name_of_profile='test1', float_value=float(1.2359))
    s = Sum_DB(name_of_profile='test2', float_value=float(2.2355))
    t = Sum_DB(name_of_profile='test3', float_value=float(4.2185))

    r.put()
    s.put()
    t.put()

    # Using the Query class
    query = Sum_DB.all()

    # You can now iterate over that 'query', with each element
    # representing an entity from your datastore. Each entity
    # will have the properties you defined in Sum_DB, so you 
    # can access them by name.
    sum_me_up = sum(result.float_value for result in query)

    # Or using GQL - the concept/result is the same
    query2 = db.GqlQuery('SELECT * from Sum_DB')
    sum_me_up2 = sum(result.float_value for result in query2)

    self.response.out.write('Query: {0} | GQL: {1}'.format(sum_me_up,
                                                           sum_me_up2))


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
                   ('/', MainHandler),
                   ],
                   debug=True)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That is exactly what I'm looking for. Your in depth answer was awesome! I wish I could award you more points...

Comment: @suitegamer No problem at all, happy to help :) Ever get that Twitch problem figured out?

Comment: It's worth noting that the above wont work for large number of results. You are limited to 30 seconds for the above request.

Comment: @Bert Agreed - as the number of returned entities grows, you will eventually have to think about splitting the request into batches (although the attribute access of the returned objects will remain the same). If it grows to that point (and if all you're doing is summing the values of the entities), it could be worth thinking about storing a 'counter' that stores the sum and adjusts with increases/decreases in the component entities.

Comment: Thanks for the info, ill keep that in mind. Yes, the twitch thing is all sorted out :P. It was all on their end, which is probably why the guys at app engine thought I was crazy or something. Whatever, I'll chalk that all up to a learning experience I suppose haha. Thanks again guys.

Comment: @suitegamer Haha, wow, well nicely done then. Happy to hear it all worked out for you! Good luck with everything.

Answer (score 0):

The mapreduce pipeline makes it easy to sum across arbitrarily large entities:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/dataprocessing/overview

You just write a mapper to sum what you want.